# Flutter, cannot show correct character while browser does

Tags: flutter

I am try to get data from a web server which include some Chinese words, the json is already in UTF8 format.  However, the character can correctly be displayed but not in Flutter.

Here is the result from browser:
[ { "ID" : 1140, "ENGLISHNAME" : "Test Name", "CHINESENAME" : "中國", "COMPANYTEL" : "", "E_ADDRESS1" : "", "E_ADDRESS2" : "", "E_ADDRESS3" : "", "C_ADDRESS1" : "", "C_ADDRESS2" : "", "C_ADDRESS3" : "" } ]

and here is the result from flutter:
[image]

```
void loadData() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.8:88/searchcustomer'),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    },
  );
  print(response.body);
}

List<dataRecord> parseJson(String responseBody) {
  final parsed =
  convert.jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<dataRecord>((json) => dataRecord.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```